# Voting widget to have a minimum of zero (no negatives)

Tags: angularjs

I have a voting widget where visitors to a site can vote up or down on their favorite game. However, visitors are able to down vote to the negatives too!

For example, if the current `voteCount` on my `game` object on the scope is set to `0`, a user can come along, press the down arrow and change it to `-1`. How can I stop this from happening?

I can do this manually by doing a check before the voting happens, but is there no angular filter to do this?

Also, what is the quickest way to allow a user a single vote instead of endless votes? Would cookies be the quickest way? or HTML5's `LocalStorage`?

**CTRL CODE**

```
    myApp.controller('VotingCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.games = [
        {
            name: 'Watch Dogs',
            description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam ut felis dapibus, bibendum dui eu.',
            imgUrl: 'img/watchdogs.jpg',
            voteCount: 0
        },
        {
            name: 'Thief',
            description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam ut felis dapibus, bibendum dui eu.',
            imgUrl: 'img/thief.jpg',
            voteCount: 0            
        },
        {
            name: 'Fifa 2014',
            description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam ut felis dapibus, bibendum dui eu.',
            imgUrl: 'img/fifa2014.jpg',
            voteCount: 0
        }
    ]

    $scope.voteUp = function(game) {
        game.voteCount += 1;
    };

    $scope.voteDown = function(game) {
        game.voteCount -= 1;
    };
});
```

Comment: What do you mean AngularJS filter? AngularJS, being a framework, called a function for you (in this case `voteDown`) - What logic goes into that function is left to you. So, put a check inside the function that ensures that the vote does not go into negative!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to change your voteDown method to not decrement if voteCount = 0.

The other way (which I would prefer) is to disable downVote button if the voteCount has reached 0, using ng-disabled. This will make it clear to the user that he/she cannot downvote anymore.

**Edit**: Pseudo Code for using ng-disabled.
In your view, you can do something like, assuming you are disabling a span.

```
<span ng-disabled="isDownVoteDisabled(game)"></span>
```

In your controller, you can define

```
$scope.isDownVoteDisabled = function(game) {
     return game.voteCount <= 0;
}
```

Abhi.

Comment: Ah. Good. Yeah, this is another alternative - put some code to show how he can use `ng-disabled`

Comment: Yes please! That would be helpful for me and future folk that come to this question.